# Cannot debug the following error message "bind_cols can't recycle"

Tags: r, vector, dplyr

I am getting the following error and because the script wasn't built by myself I am having hard time on debugging it. Nonetheless, here is the following error that I am getting and possibly the lines of codes that it's referring to:

Error:
Error in `bind_cols()`:
! Can't recycle `..1` (size 419021) to match `..2` (size 0).

Code:

```
  new_cols_as_df <- map(as.list(x),my_encoder) %>% 
    bind_cols() 
  
  input_data %>% 
    bind_cols(new_cols_as_df)
```

The script was working with identical inputs in the past and my initial thought was of possibly a library update broke the existing (perfectly working code up that that point).

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: size 0 -> See here <https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/issues/5300>

Comment: This issue is not reproducible, please add sample data.

Comment: @TarJae I saw it and still after trying everything I cannot get it to work.

Comment: It is difficult to see what is going on with the info you provide. Best is to provide a reproducible minimal example in two ways. 1. We get an idea what is going on and can help adequately and 2. you learn most by doing it this way. So far we see that you iterate over `x` (that you define as a list) where comes it from ? and then you apply a function `my_encoder` and then you use `bind_cols()` of what? .... etc....

Comment: @TarJae I totally get what you're saying and I agree, It's a type of error that even googling didn't really tell me that much. I will look around a bit more otherwise I'll try to understand more about the entire script and subsequently provide a sample that could help you understand more. Thanks though!

Comment: What output do you get when you run `dput(new_cols_as_df)`? It seems it has no rows, so it doesn't match your `input_data` with 419k rows. I get the same sort of error running `bind_cols(mtcars, mtcars[0,])` -- is that structurally the same issue as yours?